# Why am I getting some weird newlines/newline characters from my WinAPI/Crypt32 base64 Encoding function?

Tags: c, winapi, base64

I have this code, which is supposed to base64-encode a string using the crypt32.dll/WinAPI:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int encodeBase64(const char *input, char **output, DWORD *outputSize)
{
    HMODULE hCrypt32 = LoadLibrary("crypt32.dll");
    if (!hCrypt32) {
        return -2;
    }
    typedef BOOL(WINAPI *CryptBinaryToStringFunc)(const BYTE *, DWORD, DWORD, LPSTR, DWORD *);

    CryptBinaryToStringFunc cryptBinaryToString = (CryptBinaryToStringFunc)GetProcAddress(hCrypt32, "CryptBinaryToStringA");
    if (!cryptBinaryToString)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -3;
    }
    if (!cryptBinaryToString((const BYTE*)input, strlen(input), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, outputSize))
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -4;
    }
    *output = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, (*outputSize) * sizeof(char));
    if (!*output)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -5;
    }
    if (!cryptBinaryToString((const BYTE*)input, strlen(input), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, *output, outputSize))
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, *output);
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -6;
    }
    FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    LPCSTR pszSource = "Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but ...";
    char *pszDestination = NULL;
    DWORD nDestinationSize;
    int result = encodeBase64(pszSource, &pszDestination, &nDestinationSize);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        printf("Encoded string: '%s'", pszDestination);
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, pszDestination);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error in Encoding...\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
Encoded string: 'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCAuLi4='
```

But this is what I get instead:

```
Encoded string: 'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1
dCAuLi4=
'
```

Is there something wrong in my code? I was thinking this was because the base64 had `\n` in it, but apparently not, since I confirmed it by using a proper online tool.

Comment: Newlines and other whitespace are allowed anywhere in base64 and do not affect the meaning.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It was just an guess, but I got a kind of good answer already.

Comment: The base64 encoding routine is inserting that new line to make lines no longer than 64 characters.  This is common not to enlarge the individual lines more than 72 characters so they look pleasant when printed.  base64 decoding code is aware of this and will skip over whitespace, using the final `=` (or `==`) to end decoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll not claim to *completely* understand why<sup>1,2</sup> but, in order to remove those unwanted newlines in the output, Base64-encoded string, you can include the `CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF` bit in your `dwFlags` argument (using the bitwise OR operator):

```c
int encodeBase64(const char* input, char** output, DWORD* outputSize)
{
    DWORD cryptFlags = CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF; // Modify the flags
    HMODULE hCrypt32 = LoadLibrary("crypt32.dll");
    if (!hCrypt32) {
        return -2;
    }
    typedef BOOL(WINAPI* CryptBinaryToStringFunc)(const BYTE*, DWORD, DWORD, LPSTR, DWORD*);

    CryptBinaryToStringFunc cryptBinaryToString = (CryptBinaryToStringFunc)GetProcAddress(hCrypt32, "CryptBinaryToStringA");
    if (!cryptBinaryToString)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -3;
    }
    if (!cryptBinaryToString((const BYTE*)input, strlen(input), cryptFlags, NULL, outputSize))
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -4;
    }
    *output = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, (*outputSize) * sizeof(char));
    if (!*output)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -5;
    }
    if (!cryptBinaryToString((const BYTE*)input, strlen(input), cryptFlags, *output, outputSize))
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, *output);
        FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
        return -6;
    }
    FreeLibrary(hCrypt32);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Encoded string: 'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCAuLi4='
```

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa):

> CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF (0x40000000) – Do not append any new line
> characters to the encoded string. The default behavior is to use a
> carriage return/line feed (CR/LF) pair (0x0D/0x0A) to represent a new
> line.

---

<sup>1</sup> My main confusion, here, is that the description of the suggested flag states that the function will not **append** any new line characters; just how/why that applies to preventing such characters *inside* the encoded string eludes me.

<sup>2</sup> It would appear that, as mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100509/95972), the Base64 specification allows for newlines to be inserted every 76 characters. Now, with Microsoft being what they are, they appear to have changed that 'line wrap' length to 64 characters, which is the point at which your encoded string has the seemingly extraneous newline. Thanks to Sa'id Karboutli for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: For some extra clarity: I ran into this issue using the `openssl` CLI tool (generating base64 passwords). I found other Stack Overflow threads regarding this issue that explained the reasoning. I think the best answer comes from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100509) thread. Another thread on the issue: [1](https://superuser.com/q/1225134). Only odd part about OP's output is that the newline is at char 64, not 76. Though it does seem like the spec outlines *at least* 1 newline at 76 chars *max*, so perhaps the MS devs took the liberty of breaking the output at 64 chars instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this seems to work. I was honestly thinking the same thing, the new line character at the end could be probably easily deleted and was thinking the wincrypt docs would have something to that, but I wasn't really thinking it would also affect the inside one and remove it of the string. 

Do I mark your answer as working, or do we wait maybe for a better explanation?

Comment: @hoze *Do I mark your answer as working, or do we wait maybe for a better explanation?* Entirely up to you. If you found it helpful, then I'm glad. Someone *may* offer a better explanation and, if they do, I'll also be interested to see what it is.

Comment: @Sa'idKharboutli Thanks for those links. I have edited my answer to include the link you gave.

Comment: @Sa'idKharboutli, mail message format enforces lines not larger than 72 characters.  This is the reason for the magic 72 value, but encoding base64 allows to intersperse the new lineas making shorter lines.  Normally, every base64 encoder/decoder is aware of this, and offers as an options not to do it, or fix the length at which the line break is done.